# output value with html entity

Tags: javascript, html

I want my output tag to show the range value with the degree character.

```
<form>
<input type="range" value="0" name="angle" list="ranges" min="0" max="180" step="15" onchange="degree.value=value">
<output id="degree">0°</output>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b90L30wv/

How can I do ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to combine aleha and my answer to get the best of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `output` element to contain the degree sign (°), just append it to its value:

```html
<form>
<input type="range" value="0" name="angle"
  list="ranges" min="0" max="180" step="15" onchange=
  "document.getElementById('degree').value = this.value + '°'">
<output id="degree">0°</output>
</form>
```

(Although `id` attribute values can be used as global variables, if they satisfy the syntax rules for identifiers, this easily creates confusion and risks. This is why the example uses `document.getElementById('degree')` and not `degree`.)

Comment: Is not it better to do like this:

`onchange="rangeOutput.value = value + '&deg;'"` and
`<output id="rangeOutput">0&deg;</output>`

Comment: @ThomasPerez, no. Why would it be?

Comment: Ok I just read somewhere else, it is useless to put html entities in utf-8 encoded pages.

Answer (score 5):

just this:

```
<output id="degree">0</output>°
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b90L30wv/1/

Comment: An ASCII character entity should probably be used (`&#176;`)

Comment: Ok, but can't I directly put it into the onchange ? I don't think it is good to have text without tag ? And I don't want to open tags just for one character.

Comment: @ThomasPerez &#176; can be used without tag, nothing wrong with it

Comment: There is no reason to the entity `&#176;` (which is not an ASCII character), if you deal with character encodings properly, as you should anyway.

Comment: Technically, this does not do what the question asks for: to make the `output` “tag” (= element) to show the range value with the degree character. Here the degree sign is outside that element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS `after` rule:

```css
#degree::after {
    content: "°";
}

#degree {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="range" value="0" name="angle" list="ranges" min="0" max="180" step="15" onchange="degree.value=value">
<output id="degree">0</output>
</form>
```

Comment: Why so difficult. @Aleha proves that sometimes we all think to difficult.

Comment: This is far too complex for such an easy solution

Comment: A single-value, single-selector CSS rule. Far too complex. Noted. One advantage to this approach: if someone wanted to style `#degree`, they can do so without having to separately style the ° symbol, or wrap both in another container, etc.

Comment: Updated the example to demonstrate styling. Twice the complexity. Living on the edge.

Answer (score -1):

Use the word `this`

```
<form>
   <input type="range" value="0" name="angle" list="ranges" min="0" max="180" step="15" onchange="degree.value=this.value">
   <output id="degree">0°</output>
</form>
```

Or `getElementById`

```
<form>
    <input type="range" value="0" name="angle" list="ranges" min="0" max="180" step="15" onchange="document.getElementById('degree').value = this.value">
    <output id="degree">0°</output>
</form>
```

Comment: why should I add `this` ?

Comment: This answer does not address the question asked. The code overwrites the `output` value so that the degree sign is lost.